# Convert "dd/mm/yy" format to "month, day, year" in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datetime

Is there a way convert *'dd/mm/yy'* format data to *"month, day year"* in Entity Framework?
I am interested doing this with EF. I want to know EF support this or doesn't?

How can I do it?

Comment: I am interested doing this with EF))). I want to know EF support this or doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DateTime.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64.aspx) method like;

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2013, 12, 20);
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Output will be;

```
December 20, 2013
```

Here is a [**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/rsDZKh).

Comment: Answer of my question var ud = env.Select(d => new 
                         {
                             d.ReportDate.Year,
                             d.ReportDate.Month,
                             FormattedDate = d.ReportDate.ToString("yyyy-MMM")
                         })
            .Distinct()
            .OrderByDescending(d => d.Year)
            .ThenByDescending(d => d.Month)
            .Select(d => d.FormattedDate);

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime.Parse(yourString).ToString("MMMM, dd yyyy");
```

(it will give you an exception if the string's wrong).

If you already have the `DateTime`, use this:

```
yourDateTime.ToString("MMMM, dd yyyy");
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a datetime type or string value?

There is documentation for DateTime.ToString() http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx

In case you have a string, you need to parse back to datetime and then use DateTime.ToString()

Regards

Comment: Answer of my question var ud = env.Select(d => new { d.ReportDate.Year, d.ReportDate.Month, FormattedDate = d.ReportDate.ToString("yyyy-MMM") }) .Distinct() .OrderByDescending(d => d.Year) .ThenByDescending(d => d.Month) .Select(d => d.FormattedDate);